# Connecting Mysql and eclipse

Tags: java, classpath

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database hosted on phpMyAdmin and Eclipse. I have imported the JDBC bin file into the package, and I am accessing phpMyAdmin through XAMPP. This is the code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class database {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "root", "");
       System.out.println("Connection successful");
    } catch (Exception e) {
       System.err.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

However when I compile it, it says:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/test'

What does this mean? I am watching a youtube tutorial that does exact same things but has established the connection.

Comment: Check your buildpath (right-click on project -> build path -> library ) make sure mysql-jdbc.jar exists. if not - press on 'add external jar' and point to your mysql-jdbc.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register your driver first:

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Your code should be:

```
 try {
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","root","");
       System.out.println("Connection successful");
 } catch (Exception e) {
       System.err.println(e);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this before you create the connection:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

I'm not sure if you have to call the `newInstance()` method but it can't make any harm.

Note: you will have to download and include in your build path a mysql connector jar, e.g. `mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar`